# How to fix cannot resolve method 'adView' on audience network banner

Tags: java, android

I have created a online tv app and I am having problems implementing a banner ad for audience network(facebook).  When I type adView it shows the error: cannot resolve symbol 'adView'. I cannot go further without solving this error.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
if (adView != null){
adview.destroy();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Have you added dependencies in `build.gradle`? Have you declared `adView` variable in java class ?

Comment: I was following the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners , I did add the dependencies. I am new to android, how do you declare adView in Java class.

Comment: You need to declare `adView` before write `onDestroy` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I type adView it shows the error: cannot resolve symbol
>   'adView'...

The error is clear enough. Compiler could not find `adView` since you are not declaring it. To solve this, declare `adView` and initialize it inside `onCreate` method.`

```
private AdView adView;  // set as global

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
  adView = new AdView(this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);  // initialize it

  LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

  adContainer.addView(adView);

  adView.loadAd();
}
```

Comment: Thank you John Joe, it solved the problem, I hope that declaring adView is not against facebook audience network policies, I was following step by step instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners and they don't mention it.

Comment: John Joe you where right, the line private AdView adView; was there, I was distracted.